# Function to insert node in linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, hashtable

I'm reading in words from a dictionary and then adding them to linked lists in a hash table. This works fine when I try inserting the nodes for each word within the while loop.

```c
// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (dict == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Set all next pointers to NULL in hash table
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        table[i] = NULL;
    }

    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    while(fscanf(dict, "%s", word) != EOF)
    {
        // Get key from hash function
        unsigned int key = hash(word);

        node *pNode = getNode(word);

        if (table[key] != NULL)
        {
            pNode->next = table[key];
        }

        table[key] = pNode;

        words++;
    }
    fclose(dict);
    return true;
}
```

I've tried refactoring this to a function `insertNode` with the exact same code but it doesn't work and the nodes seem to get lost and cause a memory leak. I assume it has something to do with how the arguments are passed into the function but as `head` is a pointer I would've thought it would work fine.

```c
void insertNode(node *head, const char *key)
{
    // Create node
    node *pNode = getNode(key);

    // Insert node into linked list
    if (head != NULL)
    {
         // Make new node point to first item in linked list (a.k.a head)
         pNode->next = head;

    }
    // Now point head to new node
    head = pNode;
}
```

so the while loop within `load` would just call the function (which is defined before)

```c
char word[LENGTH + 1];
while(fscanf(dict, "%s", word) != EOF)
{
    // Get key from hash function
    unsigned int key = hash(word);

    // Add value to Hash table with head of linked list
    insertNode(table[key], word);

    words++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the 'head' variable is a pointer, you can just pass the value of 'head' by this pointer not the pointer itself, and in this case you try to override the local pointer inside the function.

Well look at this example to assign/change value to the pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A {
public:
    int x;
};

// pass pointer by copy
void initialize(A* obj) {

    obj = new A(); // obj not null here
    obj->x = 2;

    printf("x: %d\n", obj->x);
}

int main() {

    A *a = nullptr;

    initialize(a);

    // a is still null here (pointer passed by copy)

    printf("x: %d\n", a->x); // seg fault here, read on null

    return 0;
}
```

The following code as you can see is incorrect. To fix this example you have to change the function prototype, and pass the pointer by pointer so it should lool like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A {
public:
    int x;
};

// pass pointer by pointer
void initialize(A** obj) {

    *obj = new A(); // obj not null here
    (*obj)->x = 2;

    printf("x: %d\n", (*obj)->x);
}

int main() {

    A *a = nullptr;

    initialize(&a); // get the pointer address

    // a is valid object here

    printf("x: %d\n", a->x); // no error, x == 2

    return 0;
}
```

So in your case it should be:

```
insertNode(&table[key], word);
```

and

```
void insertNode(node **head, const char *key)
{
    // Create node
    node *pNode = getNode(key);

    // Insert node into linked list
    if (*head != NULL)
    {
         // Make new node point to first item in linked list (a.k.a head)
         pNode->next = *head;

    }
    // Now point head to new node
    *head = pNode;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the example, I'm not too familiar with that class syntax but the pass by value vs reference seems similar to implementing a function that swaps two variables. What exactly does it mean to *'pass pointer by pointer'*? Also by getting the pointer address to pass into the function, are you getting the memory address of where the pointer is in memory rather than passing the value of dereferencing the pointer? Apologies if i've misunderstood, I'm still trying to wrap my head around pointers.

Comment: I will try to explain as my best. Pointer is like a virtual finger which can be used to point on something. But that finger has to exist somewhere in the memory and it requires w few bytes of space. In the 32bit machine pointers needs 4 bytes of memory, and 8 bytes for the 64bit machine. You can simply test it with printing the value of  ```sizeof(void*)```. That is compile time constance. The pointers can be threaded as long or long long type variables, but instead of numeric value of variable, they hold the numeric address of this variable.

Comment: Pointer  size is always constant for the machine. Only the size of the pointing object can be differ. You are right, passing pointer by pointer means that you are giving this function address of the pointer in the memory, and on that address in the  numeric value of address for the next pointer, and the top layer pointer hold the object reference. Remember that there is always at least one copy operation when passing sth to the function.

Comment: But that double pointer syntax can turn out slow in some conditions. Better practice is to use single pointer and just return in on the function exit, and assign to the passed pointer. with that return, you can use your old function with added ```return head;``` in the end, and just use it like this ```table[key] = insertNode(table[key], word);```

Comment: A pointer is simply a normal variable that holds the *address of* something else as its value. In other words, a pointer *points to* the memory address where something else can be found. When you pass a pointer as a parameter to a function, the function receives a copy of the pointer with its very own (and very different) address. While you can change the value at the address held by the copy in the function, any attempt to change the address of the pointer itself simply attempts to change the address of the copy. You must pass the *address-of* the pointer to change the original in a function.